# Code Igniter form action: multiple buttons within form

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I want to do is very simple: I want to create a form using Code Igniter's form helper and place other buttons (aside from the submit button) within the form. Let me illustrate using this snippet (not my actual form):

```
<?php echo form_open('client/send_message'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="message" required />                                    
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal">Send Email</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The second button **Send Email** is supposed to open a modal. The problem is this, clicking the **Send Email** button also processes the form. So it appears you cannot have more than one button within the same form. I know I can have the Send Email button outside the form but my original form has several buttons in different places within the form and placing them outside the form will break the design. I also know that I can use `<input type="button">` within a form, but I really want to know the reason for this behavior and if there's a solution to it.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with CI; this is standard HTML behaviour. A button, or input of type "submit" within a form will submit unless you have some JavaScript which suppresses that action. You can do that with an event handler, bound to the e-mail button which, when triggered (on click), cancels the event via [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

change the type of button form submission change to submit

```
<?php echo form_open('client/send_message'); ?>
   <input type="text" name="message" required />                                    
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal">Send Email</button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Cool. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use the `a` tag for this purpose.

```
<?php echo form_open('client/send_message'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="message" required />                                    
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send</button>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_modal">Send Email</a>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button"/>
```

This will not submit the form, as we have specified it to act as a button only.

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

This will submit the form, as we have specified it to act as a button to submit a form.